# PXE boot stuck at "Start PXE over ipv4"

Tags: pxe, tftp

I have a little server at home with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. I tried configuring PXE server on it in order to deploy CloneZilla Live to other PCs in the LAN.

Everything seemed to work well, I tried booting a VM over PXE with no problem at all.

Then I activated Network Stack in my pc UEFI an got the following message

```
>>Checking Media Presence......
>>Media Present......
>>Start PXE over IPV4.
```

The PC waits a few minutes then reboots from internal SSD. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the relation between Windows Server 2012 R2 with WDS and Ubuntu 16.04 with pxelinux?

Comment: Moreover at the link you posted the guy who gets the issue tells that doing a test from a VM gives him no response from the server, while in my case CloneZilla boots in the VM.